# Why is it necessary to check for `awk` in this `bash` script?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm reading the open-source code for the "rbenv" Ruby version manager, and I see that one of this library's commands [checks whether `gawk` and `awk` are installed](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/libexec/rbenv-help#L47):

```
  awk="$(type -p gawk awk 2>/dev/null | head -n1)"
  if [ -z "$awk" ]; then
    echo "rbenv: cannot find awk" >&2
    return 1
  fi
```

But I also see a `bash` shebang at the very top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

At first I thought we should be able to assume that we can run `awk` if the shebang guarantees that we're running inside a `bash` script, but I subsequently discovered that `awk` is a UNIX command, not a shell command, and that we may be running this script file on a non-UNIX system (such as Windows).  From [this link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), I infer that `gawk` the most common flavor of `awk` for non-UNIX systems.

Am I correct that the reason we can't just assume `awk` is installed is because it is a UNIX command, and we may not be running on a UNIX machine?  And is the reason why we also check for `gawk` because it is the most-likely replacement we would expect to find on a system that doesn't have `awk` installed, i.e. a non-UNIX system?

Comment: Could be as simple as the `rbenv` folks want to show a friendly and informative error message to the human who has invoked the script, instead of a bash `awk: command not found` or a wrong-flavor-of-awk `syntax error on line 1` error.

Comment: But why wouldn't `awk` be found?  Am I correct in thinking that it's because it's not installed by default on non-UNIX machines?

Comment: `awk` is mandated by POSIX, but presumably the authors see no reason to assume this script will be running in a POSIX environment.

Comment: a user could break their `PATH` even on a POSIX system and then you're back to the "friendly error message" situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set relation between bash and awk (or gawk), other than both being executable programs, that probably exist in a `PATH` path and that both are open source, free, and developed by GNU.

A GNU executable could be perfectly valid and usable in a UNIX system. In a [Solaris system I usually use bash ([many times from the default list given by the OS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/html/817-0545/eezbb.html#scrolltoc)), no problem. And bash comply with most of the POSIX requirements. For instance: MacOS gets certified as POSIX using bash.

Linux is an OS¹ that strives to comply with the UNIX philosophy. The only reason for GNU to be defined as `GNU is not Unix` is to make it clear that Linux is **not proprietary**.

You said: *discovered that awk is a UNIX command*: Yes, it is. It also is a Linux command. And is used in Linuux, [in Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions), and in [much more than hundreds of versions](https://distrowatch.com/) of OSes. All being *nix. Also: *such as Windows* Yes, even windows has an unix layer available. And, yes GNU awk is the most common flavor of awk in *nix systems. And, yes, Windows is among the very few OS that are non *nix systems.

The reason that `awk` might not be installed is because some system developer might decide to install `nawk` (or any other executable) as the "best replacement" for `awk`, which, even being similar, has differences with `awk` (and `gawk`) which might break what the developer of `rbenv` wrote.

¹<sup>Please do not fall into the red-herring of stating that Linux [is only a kernel](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/what-is-linux). The generally called Linux is an OS with the kernel developed by Linus and a group of opensource user tools, generally from GNU.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I suspect they may also be using that `awk` variable later in their code, e.g. `"$awk" 'script' file`, otherwise they should've just written `if ! type -p gawk awk >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...error...`. If they use the variable they'll be using either gawk or some other awk, whichever is first in their PATH, without it they'd presumably write `awk 'script' file` and potentially miss a gawk earlier in their PATH.

Ah, looks like that's correct, If you look at a bit more of [their code](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/libexec/rbenv-help#L46):

```
  awk="$(type -p gawk awk 2>/dev/null | head -n1)"
  if [ -z "$awk" ]; then
    echo "rbenv: cannot find awk" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  # shellcheck disable=SC2016
  "$awk" '
    /^Summary:/ {
      summary = substr($0, 10)
      next
    }
```

So what they're really trying to do is find the first version of awk or gawk in their PATH and use that, the failure if neither is present is IMHO more of a defensive afterthought.